# Implementing a java SSL and TLS server socket with client authentication

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, tcp, server

I'm working on a project which consists on developping a TLS and SSL JAVA TCP/IP (Socket) server.

The Server must accept TLS and SSL TCP/IP Connections.

Actually i developed a multithreaded Server which can accept and respond to many clients in the same time but i still don't see a solution to make it work with TLS and SSL connections

I have read about the `SSLServerSocket` and `ServerSocketFactory` but I didn't get how can they help me with the certificate:

I didn't know how to give the socket The CA file path (the private certificate path)  (e.g: CAfile=D:\projects\mytools\eclipse\TunRootCA1.pem or rootcert.crt) like in Stunnel

let me describe the situation more precisely:
actually, the project i'm working on, consists on developing a server JAVA application which connects with POS devices working with TLS or SSL certificate.
The server has to accept the flow and make some fonctional controles (such as amounts,PAN, ...) then switch it to a third party server.
The server has to work with a one side certificate verification:
the clients use a certificate (.ca) downloaded from a national authority web site and the server uses a certificate signed from the same national authority agency
all parts of the server are ready except the TLS and SSL connection
thanks

I'd appreciate if anyone can describe me steps (with code samples) to implement a JAVA SSL and TLS server TCP/IP socket (with the above described behaviour)

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't understand why you are now respecifyng how TLS works. It isn't part of your requirement at all. Your requirement as it now appears is merely to use TLS. Your actual question has nothing whatsoever to do with points 1-5.

Comment: let me describe the situation more precisely:
actually, the project i'm working on, consists on developing a server JAVA application which connects with POS devices working with TLS or SSL certificate.
The server has to accept the flow and make some fonctional controles (such as amounts,PAN, ...) then switch it to a third party server.
The server has to work with a one side certificate verification:
the clients use a certificate (.ca) downloaded from a national authority web site and the server uses a certificate signed from the same national authority agency

Comment: Actually your points 1 to 5 (actually, *my* points) are not part of this problem or this requirement in any way and should be removed from the question. You should study the JSSE Reference Guide and come back when you have a real question.

Comment: your points (actually, standard points which you have explained clearly) are just an additional description nothing else.
About the JSSE Reference Guide, thanks again for the advise, and i'll start study them from now
My question will stay the same for any one who want help (like you did)

Comment: They are pointless and irrelevant and I am removing them. You don't need to re-specify TLS here, and there is nothing you can do that would *prevent* those steps from happening, let alone cause them, provided only you *use* TLS and implement your keystores and truststores correctly, which is what your question is actually about.

Comment: Ok, whatever, as you want,  can you provide some help now??

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not how TLS/SSL works.

> The client initiates a connection and sends a public certificate to my server

The client initiates a connection, receives the server certificate, verifies it, receives a certificate request from the server, and sends its own certificate if it can.

> The server must authentify the certificate received with its private certificate (stocked in some predefined path)

Meaningless. There is no such thing as a private certificate. The server verifies the certificate (a) by checking its digital signature and (b) by forming a trust chain from its signer to a signer it trusts.

> The server sends a positive response back to the client.

The server either completes the TLS/SSL handshake or sends a TLS alert or closes the connection. There is no positive response to an accepted client certificate.

> The client sends its message to the server (clear messages).

The channel is now encrypted in both directions.

> The server sends its responding messages to the client (clear message).

The channel is now encrypted in both directions.

Your requirement is both non-TLS-compliant and insecure as stated. Review it.

Comment: Thanks alot for the detailed and precise explanations.
i may miss proposed the scenario (because i understood wrongly the TLS/SSL functioning.
I rearranged my post based on your precious explanation

Warm regards